# StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript Escape Single Quote

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, stringescapeutils

I have 2 types of text string that I need to escape:

1) name=ALICE "  (double quote)

2) name=ALICE ' (single quote)

**This is my codes:**

```
if (name.indexOf('\'') >= 0){
        name=StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript(name);
        System.out.println("escape by javascript " + name);

} else {
        name=StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(name);
        System.out.println("escape by html" + name);

}
```

The solution works correctly for both ( able to save both name texts in database)

1) [details-doublequote.jsp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slRfM.png)

2) [details-singlequote.jsp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RUTF.png)

However, the display is a bit off. How can I hide the backslash character from showing when escaping the single quote? I want the jsp to display **ALICE'** instead if **ALICE\'** & ensure able to save the result in db

Comment: While showing you unescape that string`StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJavaScript(name);`

Comment: if I do this: StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJavaScript(name), I can't save the result in db

Comment: You save in DB  whatever String escape and while showing you can unescape.

Comment: Hi @soorapadman.. thanks for your input.. I've fixed the issue, by placing the codes just before edit event.. previously, I put the codes under search event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed!
Instead of putting the codes directly inside `public ActionForward search (){}`

in the JSP file, assign decorator class

```
<display:table sort="list" style="width: 100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" class="mydataTable" excludedParams="*" name="custTable" defaultsort="1" defaultorder="ascending" requestURI="<%=uri%>" pagesize="20" decorator="com.aza.util.MyDecorator">            
        <display:column style="width: 150px;" titleKey="customer.name" property="name" sortable="true" headerClass="sortable tabledisplay"/>    
    </display:table>
```

in the decorator class, *MyDecorator.java*

```
    MyModel cusModel = (MyModel) getCurrentRowObject();
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();

    String customerName=cusModel.getName();

    if (customerName.indexOf('\'') >= 0){
        customerName=StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript(customerName);          
    } else {
        customerName=StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(customerName);            
    }

    cusModel.setName(customerName);
```